# Frameless window not draggable - Mac OSX

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos, electron

When the frameless window is created on Mac [OSX 10.8.5] there is no way to drag it anymore?

```
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    frame: false,
    resizable: false,
    width: 500,
    height: 300
});
```

I found from the [docs](https://github.com/atom/electron/blob/master/docs/api/frameless-window.md) that assigning the `-webkit-app-region: drag` style to the body element should fix it, but for some reason the window is just glued to the initial place.

I haven't test it on Windows or Linux yet. Does anyone seen that issue before?

---

[EDIT 04.11.2015]

I've tested the app on the Windows machine and it is draggable. This is Mac related issue. Will try to create new issue in GitHub repo.

---

[EDIT 04.11.2015]

It's confirmed that's a bug with the version v0.34.2 of Electron. Temporary solution solution is to downgrade to v0.34.0.

Can be tracked on GitHub, [Issue #3329](https://github.com/atom/electron/issues/3329)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is related to the OSX bug, Chrome already dropped the support for the Mac OSX 10.8 version so the bug won't be fixed. Solution is to use v0.34.0 of Electron or update the OS.

More info can be found in the [Issue #3329](https://github.com/atom/electron/issues/3329)

Answer (score 3):

Is this only happening when devTools is open ? I had exactly the same issue, i.e. dragging worked Windows, not OSX. Found out that my issue was related to devTools. Hopefully, this saves someone else some time:

**On OSX, devTools must be closed** for `-webkit-app-region: drag;` to work!

(electron v1.3.1)

Comment: It is also good to know, that if you use googleDevTools in separate window, dragging works, problem is only with electron app with devTool in the same window.

Answer (score 2):

Just make 2 css classes and apply them to whatever item you want, at least it works perfectly with div and h1. Tested on windows and linux

```
.drag-area {
  -webkit-app-region: drag;
}

.nodrag-area {
  -webkit-app-region: no-drag;
}
```

**E.g:**

```
<header class="toolbar toolbar-header drag-area">
    <h1 class="title">Photon</h1>
</header>
```